# How to run an application on target pc via network

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, private-network, remote-execution

I have two computers in Private Network: one is laptop and another is a desktop PC with Remote Connection Disabled.

How can I run an application from the laptop on the desktop PC without using Remote Desktop Connection?

The target PC (the desktop) runs Windows 7, whereas the source PC (the laptop) runs Windows Vista. Both computers are on the same subnet and can properly send and receive data between each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)**, from SysInternals, can do just this, providing you have the credentials to access the other computer.

> Utilities like Telnet and remote
>   control programs like Symantec's PC
>   Anywhere let you execute programs on
>   remote systems, but they can be a pain
>   to set up and require that you install
>   client software on the remote systems
>   that you wish to access. PsExec is a
>   light-weight telnet-replacement that
>   lets you execute processes on other
>   systems, complete with full
>   interactivity for console
>   applications, without having to
>   manually install client software.
>   PsExec's most powerful uses include
>   launching interactive command-prompts
>   on remote systems and remote-enabling
>   tools like IpConfig that otherwise do
>   not have the ability to show
>   information about remote systems.

Comment: but i have to install the service on the target pc first right?

Comment: no, there is nothing to install on the target pc

Comment: the program does run a temporary service on the remote computer, but it's removed during cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

if the two computers are close to each other (in sight), you can use **[Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/)**. other than that, you can remotely excute commands on another machine via telnet or **[PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)**.